# Check if string is codepage 1250 compliant

Tags: php, mysql

I need to check if a string is codepage 1250 compliant.

I can write it to MySQL and do a check like this:

```
select id,name from test where name <> CONVERT(name USING cp1250);
```

That will find non-compliant strings.

Can I do the same in PHP somehow?

Comment: If you can do it in mysql, then just make a call from php to mysql.

Comment: I'd like to avoid that roundtrip to the database as I need to do it often.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
mb_convert_case($name, MB_CASE_LOWER, "Windows-1251")
```

or maybe

```
mb_convert_encoding($name,"Windows-1251")
```

Comment: The actual function to use is [mb_check_encoding()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-check-encoding.php) for this purpose. But mbstring doesn't support Windows-1250, and AFAIK Windows 1250 != Windows 1251.

Comment: My understanding is that Windows 1251 is close enough to 1250. like a 90% match.